# How to resolve error "Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output."?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, authentication

I am facing an error as per below at admin panel login.

> **"ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output."**

I've tried several solutions like,

1. **Log checking** (No logs are showing in log file)
2. Resolve **header already sent** issue (Not getting this error at
   all).
3. Check incomplete '**php tag**', removing white spaces etc (Have
   already checked both).
4. **Renaming Plugins** folder
5. **Renaming Theme** folder

We have re-solve above 5 things but still the issue is there.

Would anyone please check this and help me on this ?
[image]

Comment: In order to prevent WordPress' error control override, you need to enable its debug mode by setting `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in wp-config.php.  This will probably output the error you're looking for.

Comment: @JuliePelletier already enable debug mode and check it, but i don't get any error regarding this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. What I did is I added ob_start() at top of wp-config.php then it allows me logged in. After that I update one of plugin that was requite to update. Then I logout and removed ob_start() and I surprised error was gone and never came again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing file formats (UTF-8 BOM to UTF-8)
Renaming Plugins folder
Replacing Files which are giving error (On enabling wp-debug)

Or upgrade the WordPress, or more likely you can say replacing core WordPress files using FTP. I followed this guide for manual upgrade: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress

Comment: thanks for giving reply but we already tried this solution, but it want work.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem. I want to stress that it's sometimes impossible to tell that there is a blank space at the beginning of a php file (like functions.php as it was in my case) cause it might be a Byte Order Mark which is impossible. I could not make my site work although I checked most php files and found no blank spaces in the beginning of files. There was this plugin, Updraft plus that created a warning insisting that there was a byte order mark at the beginning of functions.php and led me to create a new file and copy paste the content as text. I got a 3bytes smaller file which was all I needed to fix my site and get it working again.

Here is an image of the old (with the BOM) and the new functions.php side to side. It's impossible to tell that there is an issue there.
[image: Old and new functions.php side by side comparison]